# Collect coefficients of non-square matrix in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, sympy

Given three vectors, `a`(1,4), `b`(1, 4), `c`(4,1). I want to do the following

```py
a = MatrixSymbol('a', 1, 4)
b = MatrixSymbol('a', 1, 4)
c = MatrixSymbol('c', 4, 1)

expr = a*c + b*c
c_coeff = .... # How to get the value of (a+b) here
```

I tried using `coeff` and `collect` but it fails because the C matrix is not square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is linear then

```py
>>> from sympy.solvers.solveset import linear_coeffs
>>> linear_coeffs(expr, c)
[a + b, 0]
```

note that 0 is the constant term; if you added `MatrixSymbol('d', 1, 1)` to `expr` the 2nd element would be `d`; you named 'b' as 'a' in your example; I named it 'b' to get the output shown above.

Comment: It is indeed linear in c